# Loop through array and pass keys to function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to pass each element in events_sections array to a function, I keep getting nil, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
event_sections = ["a_full","b_full","c_full","e_full","h_full","i_full","k_full","z_full"]
    event_sections.each do |key|
       @events[key] = Zlib.inflate(Events_Full_Sections.first."#{key}")
    end 
    render json: @events
```

Your help is highly appreicated

Comment: What exactly is `nil`? Are you getting any other error? Are you sure `Events_Full_Sections` is not blank?

Comment: I'll be really surprised if  that is (`Events_Full_Sections`) a model name :)

Comment: Yeah, thats the model name

Answer (score 0):

I presume you don't have `@events` defined earlier. So, define a empty array with that variable before the loop:

```
@events = []
```

Also, if `Events_Full_Sections` is a model, we don't call methods with interpolation like you tried. We use `send` method to call a method with str/symbol name. Like this:

```
event_sections = ["a_full","b_full","c_full","e_full","h_full","i_full","k_full","z_full"]
@events = []

event_sections.each do |key|
   @events[key] = Zlib.inflate(Events_Full_Sections.first.send(key))
end 
render json: @events
```

I've not sure about your DB structure, so I assume it would work.

You might also save `Events_Full_Sections.first` in a variable outside loop, to avoid calling to db everytime.